# Change default PO form for a role based on condition

Tags: netsuite

I have a requirement where I need to default certain fields on the PO form if the particular PO is created from MRP. I have created a summary field which will result data if the PO is created from a planned order. Now I need to default certain fields only for a role in this case. I was thinking of creating another custom form and defaulting all the fields using a workflow and call it only when the summary field has a value. The defaulting should not happen in other cases.

Please advice on the best  approach on this, I am not much proficient in scripting yet.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this either via script or workflow,In case of a workflow default the values of the fields with the condition of your summary field and the role.If you want to do it in script something like this will help you

var userObj = runtime.getCurrentUser();
log.debug("Internal ID of current user role: " + userObj.role);

var userObj = runtime.getCurrentUser();
log.debug("Custom script ID of current user role: " + userObj.roleId);